# Espacios en blanco en funciones LESS

Tags: css, less

Me aparece un espacio en blanco entre variable y constante. Al renderizarse en el navegador, este lo interpreta como atributo no válido como es de esperar.

En la versión inglesa me han comentado, bueno, marcado como duplicada la pregunta, pero no es exactamente igual, ya que en las respuestas que me dieron, no se hacía aritmética, sino que eran atributos ya dados fijos.

**INPUT:**

```
.generateDelay(5);
.generateDelay(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    &:nth-child(@{i}) { 
        animation-delay: (.25*@i)s;
    }
    .generateDelay(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
animation-delay: 0.25 s;
animation-delay: 0.5 s; //etc
```

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poner la "unidad de medida" en la operación

```
.generateDelay(5);
.generateDelay(@n, @i:2) when (@i =< @n) {
   &:nth-child(@{i}) {
      @b: (.25s*@i);
       animation-delay: @b;
    }
   .generateDelay(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Eso también me comentaron en la web inglesa.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es usar la función [unit](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit):

**Less**

```
.generateDelay(5);
.generateDelay(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    &:nth-child(@{i}) { 
      animation-delay: unit((.25*@i),s);
    }
    .generateDelay(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

**CSS**

```
:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}
:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, esta opción también me la comentaron, aunque no se porque comentan que no se suele usar

Comment: Pues no tengo ni idea, es una función que sirve para eso precisamente, también para extraer el valor sin la unidad. La solución de @aloMalbarez es más elegante y limpia (incluso sobra la variable `@b`) pero creo que esta opción es válida también y por eso la pongo como alternativa

Comment: Si merci, le di el voto positivo ;)